# $X_k$ are $\mathcal U(0,2\theta)$ distributed, and $Y_n=\max_{1\leq k < n}X_k$, how is $F_{Y_n}=(\frac{t-\theta}{\theta})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X_k$ are $\mathcal U(0,2\theta)$ distributed, and $Y_n=\max_{1\leq k < n}X_k$, how is $F_{Y_n}(t)=(\frac{t-\theta}{\theta}),\theta<t<2\theta\ \ ?$

$F_{Y_n}(t) \text{ aka }(CDF)$;
This does not seem intuitively correct and why is $t$ restricted to this interval?

Comment: Where did you find this? Indeed $Y_n$ can take values less than $θ$, so this does not seem correct.

Comment: How about this CDF, does that have any truth to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that $X_k$'s are independent.
\begin{align}
\Pr\{Y_n\leq t\}&=\Pr\{\max_{k}X_k\leq t\}\\
&=\Pr\{X_1\leq t,X_2\leq t,...,X_n \leq t\}\\
&=\Pr\{X_1\leq t\}\Pr\{X_2\leq t\}...\Pr\{X_n \leq t\}\\
&=F_{X_1}(t)F_{X_2}(t)...F_{X_n}(t)\\
&=\frac{t}{2\theta}\frac{t}{2\theta}...\frac{t}{2\theta}\\
&=\left(\frac{t}{2\theta}\right)^n
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

$$F_{Y_n}(t)=F_X(t)^n        $$